# Iterating through all IP addresses in a CIDR using java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, design-patterns

I want to know if there is any way to explode IPs of CIDR format. Along with exploding this code should take care of considering 'exclude' feature also.

To be precise, I want something that takes something like 172.21.3.128/30(Inclusion list:172.21.3.128/30) and returns

- 172.21.3.128
- 172.21.3.129
- 172.21.3.130
- 172.21.3.131

And if it has exclusion list as '172.21.3.130'(Inclusion list:172.21.3.128/30 & exclusion list:172.21.3.130) then it should return

- 172.21.3.128
- 172.21.3.129
- 172.21.3.131

Currently I explode inclusion list & keep in Set and explode exclusion list & keep in set.And take the difference between two.Problem with this approach is I have to keep all exploded IPs in memory which might create problem(outofmemoryerror) if range is very big.

Comment: It should be possible to implement the different set operations (union, subtraction) without exploding the ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for inclusion list, you can use a [SubnetUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html) class of Apache Commons Net to get all the addresses, like:

```
String subnet = "192.168.0.0/24";
SubnetUtils utils = new SubnetUtils(subnet);
String[] addresses = utils.getInfo().getAllAddresses();
```

But it seems, that you need to do exclusions by yourself in that case, because it's not nativly supported in such a utils. So, you can simply make a Collections of all addresses and remove from it all addresses, which should be excluded.